# .sh script returning branch name locally, but returns HEAD when run inside a github action

Tags: github-actions

I am trying to access the branch name of the current PR inside a shell script that is triggered by a new commit. When I run the following locally, my terminal successfully prints out the branch name:

```bash
BRANCH_NAME=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
echo $BRANCH_NAME
```

However, if I run this in a github action, it instead prints out `HEAD`. Does anyone know why this discrepancy might happen, and what I can do to fix it?

It's important to note that I'm **not** trying to access the branch name in the workflow yaml file. I know that can be done with github's existing properties.

Comment: When `HEAD` is detached, `git rev-parse --abbrev-rev HEAD` prints `HEAD`. So `HEAD` must be detached. Why *that* is, is up to GitHub and GitHub actions; there's nothing shell or generic Git about this.

Comment: I think that happens it you are in `detached HEAD` state. Are you sure it is working on a local branch?